# Trouble with promises bluebird in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a module in node.js, that connect with postgres database through sequelize lib. My module code basically is:

```
// ofr-network/index.js
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var models = requireDir('./models');

var network = {
  getReportsFromCity: function(cityId) {
    models.index.reports.findAll({
      where: { id: cityId },
      attributes: ['id', 'latitude', 'longitude']
    }).then(function(reports) {
      console.log('[NETWORK-OFR] Get reports from %s', cityId);
      return reports;
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('Error getting reports from %s', cityId);
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = network;
```

Well, this code works fine. Now I'm trying use this module in my express application, importing and calling this method, but this code isn't return anything. I've searched, and see that I must to use promises, once this code above is async. 
My API method code is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var network = require('ofr-network');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var getReports = Promise.promisify(network.getReportsFromCity, network);
  getReports(538).then(function(reports) {
    console.log('DONE');
    // this print isn't running
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.render('index.html', { title: 'Title page' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why do you promisify `getReports`? Promisify is for making callback functions return promises, `getReports` already returns a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises represent a value + time. Promises have state, they start as pending and can settle to:

- **fulfilled** meaning that the computation completed successfully.
- **rejected** meaning that the computation failed.

Functions that return promises (like sequelize functions) let you hook on those promises with `then` that runs when the previous promise fulfilled. You can chain promises (like you've done) but don't forget to `return` them to the outside. Promises utilize return values for hooks.

`Promise.promsify` takes a function that takes a callback in the `(err, data)` format - it is not necessary in your code that already uses promises. It's useful for [promisification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) which is not the case here.

Instead - you just need to return the promise so you can use it:

```
var network = {
  getReportsFromCity: function(cityId) {
    return models.index.reports.findAll({ // NOTE THE RETURN
      where: { id: cityId },
      attributes: ['id', 'latitude', 'longitude']
    }).then(function(reports) {
      console.log('[NETWORK-OFR] Get reports from %s', cityId);
      return reports;
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('Error getting reports from %s', cityId);
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
network.getReportsFromCity(538).then(function(data){
    console.log("Data", data);
});
```

Don't forget that promises do not convert asynchronous code to synchronous code and are just a useful tool - not magic :) Everything *outside* the promise chain can still happen before the chain itself runs. Your `res.render` is misplaced - you need to put it in the final `then` with the relevant data.

Comment: Tks so much. It's works fine! And thanks for your explanation about promises. :)

Comment: @marciovicente.filho I'm glad I could help - feel free to ask more promise questions when they - we're trying to create a knowledge base here :)

Answer (score 0):

could you try to put line `res.render('index.html', { title: 'Title page' });` after line `console.log('DONE');` ?
It seems the response were called before you get to the `getReports` result.

Comment: Hey @ChinKang, I already try put rende into `then` but it doesn't works.